# Cordova/Phonegap and HTML5 App cache on Android

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm trying to make an app which is available to users while offline, but updates if it's online . So i was thinking about using the HTML5 cache just for that, caching up the most recent version. The problem is , sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt. I have an index.html page in my Cordova App which sets your window.location to the http online link. Why wouldn't it work all the time? I have my manifest.appcache configured and mime-types enabled, sometimes it will just show a blank page not found ,even though it downloaded a page which included a manifest. Is there anything i'm missing? I put the link setting in index.html after the javascript body load event. It's android that i'm testing , so far i tried with an Iphone 1 time and it worked.

If you guys know more, please share